# Unable to create a new listener in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, listener

In net manager i get an error message "**A valid logfile is required"** when i click on listener and choose '+' button. and then it keeps on giving me that error when i click on any other tab or button in net manager.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://oracle.itags.org/q_oracle_72378.html).

It basically says:

> For Windows goto command prompt and type lsnrctl and hit enter
>
> ```
> LSNRCTL> SET LOG_DIRECTORY X:/oracle/admin/    
> LSNRCTL> SET LOG_FILE XXXX.log
> ```
>
> For linux or unix connect as oracle user and then type lsnrctl and hit enter
>
> ```
> LSNRCTL> SET LOG_DIRECTORY /XXX/oracle/admin    
> LSNRCTL> SET LOG_FILE XXXx.log
> ```
>
> after doing this now configure the listner if not configured from netmanger and start it.you should have permissions to directory which u are giving in set log_directory command.

<sup>*(original grammar, spelling and punctuation preserved)*</sup>

---

<sub>**EDIT 14-Apr-2016**

That link appears to be dead now, use [this one](https://community.oracle.com/message/1353239#1353239) for reference instead.</sub>